# What technology stack does Stack Overflow use for its development?

Tags: support

What technology stack does Stack Overflow use for development?

Comment: Stack Overflow mainly runs on Microsoft stuff, MSSql, ASP .NET etc.

Comment: Duplicate: [which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/)

Comment: but of course we can't mark it as such because of the stupid split

Comment: I wouldn't use a technology just because Stack Exchange uses it. Their enterprise and yours may be very different - it depends what you have in play at the moment, what skills your developers have, how easy it is to hire for each skill in your area, and various other factors.

Comment: There is an article on High Scalability: http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html

Comment: Another example of the need for cross-site dupes.  No one should be voting this down since it's a fine question Meta question, that's been asked on another site.

Comment: @LanceRoberts "We have analyzed..." I read this sentence, and just wanted to say "GOOD JOB." Sounds more like practicing for a job interview or a consultancy sales pitch than a question. Everything after the first sentence is probably drawing the downvotes.

Comment: @Chris, yes, it could have been written better.

Comment: A related question that I often wonder (but do not have enough serious interest to research) is whether the SO software is available for purchase by other enterprises (or whether SO offers the "service" to other enterprises).  I would guess that some large organizations could use it.

Comment: Not that it matters, but my own network uses a mixture of Windows, MySQL, MSSQL, Linux, and PHP. Stack Exchange operates along a similar line of that.

Answer (score 13):

jQuery, of course.

You can find the full list of tools here: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: jQuery, hand-drawn circles, a herd of unicorns and some insignificant stuff as outlined in that post.

Comment: The database is even in jQuery. All the things.

Comment: Have you considered SPA?